# Medir tiempo de ejecución en PHP

Tags: php, rendimiento

Estoy intentando obtener el tiempo de ejecución de una operación que corre de forma iterativa, pero al intentar comparar, obtengo 0 segundos.

```
$startedAt = time();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    // Solo como código demostrativo.
    preg_match('/^0{3}\b/', $number);
}
$finishedAt = time();

echo 'Tiempo: ' . ($finishedAt - $startedAt);
```

Buscando en php.net no encuentro una función alterna, ¿existe otra solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con [microtime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php)

```
    $start = microtime(true);

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
// Solo como código demostrativo.
 preg_match('/^0{3}\b/', $number); }

    $end = microtime(true);
    $time = $end-$start;
    echo "execute time {$time}";
```